# SQL Server - Geography

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gis, geography

Given a linestring, if I construct a circle around the start point of the said linestring, I would expect the circle to intersect the linestring.

```
declare @startPoint geography = geography::Point(51.947859,3.986790,4326)
declare @endPoint geography = geography::Point(51.956383,3.995908,4326)
declare @g geography = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(51.947859 3.986790, 55.956383 3.995908)', 4326).MakeValid()  -- The linestring

select 
    @startPoint.STDistance(@endPoint) -- is 1136.88182010473 metres

declare @h geography = @startPoint.STBuffer(50) -- The Circle

select 
    @g.STIntersection(@h).STEndPoint().Long,@g.STIntersection(@h).STStartPoint().Long

select 
    @g.STIntersects(@h) -- Why is this false(0)?
```

I need some help in understanding why the circle and the linestring do not intersect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
When I define @startPoint as:

```
set  @startPoint = geography::Point(51.947859,3.986790,4326)
```

The point, as text is:

```
select @startpoint.ToString() -- result= POINT (3.98679 51.947859)
```

When I define @startPoint as:

```
set @startPoint= geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.947859 3.986790)',4326)
```

The point as text is:

```
select @startpoint.ToString() -- POINT (51.947859 3.98679)
```

In other words, the first syntax takes latitude,longitude while the second takes longitude, latitude. 
**The second syntax is the one to use**.
By design or by accident, this is nothing short of a trap for developers.